# How is FormGroup directive used in template driven forms?

Tags: angular, forms, ngmodel

I understand that an instance of `FormGroup` in a component's class can be linked to the form in the template in Reactive Forms to validate its input fields. However I do not get how do we use `FormGroup` in Template-driven forms. What is the difference between `ngModel` and `FormGroup`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Template-driven Forms: FormGroup**

In template driven forms, Angular binds to the FormGroup directive automatically when you use the `<form>` tag in your application.

[image]

As shown in the diagram, you can use a template reference variable (denoted with a `#`) to get the reference to the FormGroup. This then gives you access to the form state, such as the validity state so you can do things like disable a Save button until the values are valid.

```
 <button type="submit"
         [disabled]="!signupForm.valid">
   Save
  </button>
```

You don't *have* to define a template reference variable for the form ... only if you need it as shown in the `button` example above.

**Template-driven Forms: ngModel**

You use `ngModel` to two-way bind an *input element* on the form with a *property* in the component. In the example below, we bind the *input* element to a `customer.firstName` property in the component.

[image]

By using `ngModel` **and** setting the `name` attribute, Angular will automatically define a `FormControl` for the control and add it to the `FormGroup`

Here again we can use a template reference variable (denoted with a `#`) to reference the FormControl and access the control's state, such as touched or dirty or validation errors.

This is often used to display validation error message like this:

```
<span *ngIf="firstNameVar.errors">
  Please enter your first name.
</span>
```